# How to access hashMaps in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, hashmap

I have an interesting problem: I cannot access my hashmap keys.

I have the following hashmap:

```
{a=Retrieve User Account call failed, b=This user has multiple accounts}
```

I get blank variables when I do any of the following:

```
"${myMap.get('a')}"
"${myMap['a']}"
"${myMap.a}"
```

I get false values from:

```
"${myMap.containsKey('a')}"
"${myMap.keySet().contains('a')}"
```

But I get true when I do:

```
"${myMap.keySet()[1] == 'a'}"
```

What's the problem? And how can I invoke `contains` on either the hashmap keys or on the keySet to find out if 'a' is in the hash/list?

If it helps any, I'm using groovy 2.3.0-rc-2 plugin for Groovy/Grails Tool Suite and grails 2.4.1

Comment: That's not a valid hashmap, that looks to be some kind of really broken JSON.

Comment: What you are describing isn't really possible but given the way you represent the Map in your example it is hard to say if it is even a Map.  That aside, if you have a Map that has the key "a" in it and the value associated with that key is the String "Retrieve User Account call failed", then `myMap.get('a')`, `myMap['a']` and `myMap.a` will all evaluate to the String "Retrieve User Account call failed".

Comment: @JoshuaMoore it's not broken JSON, it's the standard `toString()` of a java Map.

Comment: @IanRoberts Ah yes! Indeed it is!

Comment: What are `a` and `b` here? Are they definitely strings rather than (say) GStrings? How exactly is the map initialized?

Comment: The behavior described in the question isn't possible in standard Groovy.  It is possible that your application has some broken metaprogramming in it that is screwing this up but more likely there is a mistake in the code somewhere and/or something in the description above is false.  If you can reproduce this in a runnable app I am sure it is a 15 second research mission to identify what the problem is.  If you create that app I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: How are you putting the key `a` and its value into the map? If your key is a `GStringImpl` rather than a `String`, I think you could see the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Surely he would have said if the keys were anything other than a String. That seems an important detail to omit.

Comment: Yeh, but who hasn't fallen into the `myMap."${someString}" = someValue` trap before...

Answer (score 1):

This may be a duplicate question, but I am going to answer it anyway.  Your syntax in Groovy is a bit off.

See here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections

Their examples:

```
def map = [name:"Gromit", likes:"cheese", id:1234]
assert map.get("name") == "Gromit"
assert map.get("id") == 1234
assert map["name"] == "Gromit"
assert map['id'] == 1234
assert map instanceof java.util.Map

def emptyMap = [:]
assert emptyMap.size() == 0
emptyMap.put("foo", 5)
assert emptyMap.size() == 1
assert emptyMap.get("foo") == 5
```

Your map:

```
def map = [a:"Retrieve User Account call failed", 
    b:"This user has multiple accounts"]

assert map.get("a") == "Retrieve User Account call failed"
// also
assert map.a == "Retrieve User Account call failed"
```

Comment: The assertions that you have there with single equals are invalid.  You need double equals.